# IOS SWIFT5: check is specific field odcument exist in firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Seems there's no way to use boolean to return the checking result is exist or not. it only works in printing out the result...

```
    func checkSeatAvailable() -> Bool{
       var Exist: Bool
       let g = DispatchGroup()
        let resDate = ResDateTxt.text
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("Reservations").whereField("resDate", isEqualTo: resDate!)
        g.enter()
        docRef.getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
                                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                                    if snapshot.isEmpty {
                                            print("Document does not exist")
                                        Exist =  true
                                        g.leave()
                                         } else {
                                        print("Document data: \(snapshot) ")
                                        Exist = false
                                        g.leave()
                                        }
                                    }
        }
        g.notify(queue:.main) {}
        print("\(Exist)")
        return Exist
    }
```

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous. getDocuments returns immediately, before the query is complete. The callback you provide is executed some time later. You can only use the result of the query after the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `completion Handler` in your function as `getDocuments` function is asynchronous and return immediately. You can modify it like so.

```
func checkSeatAvailable(Completion:@escaping((Bool)->())){
 //let g = DispatchGroup()
   let resDate = ResDateTxt.text
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   let docRef = db.collection("Reservations").whereField("resDate", isEqualTo: resDate!)
    //g.enter()
    docRef.getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
         if let snapshot = snapshot {
              if snapshot.isEmpty {
                     print("Document does not exist")
                     //g.leave()
               } else {
                         print("Document data: \(snapshot) ")
                          Completion(true)
                           //g.leave()
                       }
                    }
                }
    
    //g.notify(queue:.main) {}
    //print("\(Exist)")
    //return Exist
}
```

And then call that function like that;

```
checkSeatAvailable { (boolValue) in
      
      print(boolValue)
 }
```